# Screen not registering all inputs (touchscreen isnt broken)

Tags: screen

So i recently got a new phone, its good but ive noticed an issue with it. For whatever reason the screen isnt registering inputs but it like is at the same time (hard to explain)

So if i go into developer options and turn on the show touch coordinates, it will show all of my inputs im doing on the screen fully accurately. The issue is that the game im playing isnt being told about these inputs at all and acting like they arent there. (not an issue with the game itself, this happens everywhere, even on the home screen.)

So the physical screen itself is fully fune but there is some kind of artificial limitation in the software or whatever.. and im wondering if i could fix it somehow, like flash a rom or change some setting or some screen repair app

here is a few demonstration videos: https://youtu.be/pJLiaXRxzWA (the display showing the inputs are happening but thing no work work)

https://youtu.be/I8RUbMgNnGM (press finger on screen screen no do thing bla bla bla..)

The phone is Poco x3 nfc by xiaomi, running android 10, MIUI global 12.0.4 stable

and if anyone knows a better place to post this to get better answers please tell me

Comment: Use a screen test app (e.g. [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.anton_mokshyn.touchscreentest) to check if you have dead regions.

Comment: watched the videos and all i can see is touch is working fine - so what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that inputs are being dropped. idk how you watched those 2 videos and came to that conclusion

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for few days, on the same phone. First try enabling 'show pointer' in developer options. If touches are detected but not registered or occassionally omitted, switch off device for 5 mins, and turn back on. Worked for me!